# Why I can't access a column of temporary created relation when using update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to increment the salaries of instructors who earn less than the average of all instructors by 5%. I don't want to recalculate the average in the where clause i.e

```sql
    update instructor
    set salary = salary * 1.05
    where salary < (select avg (salary)
                from instructor);
```

since the average will be calculated for each check in the where clause which would be very inefficient. Also the salaries in the instruction relation are being updated which would change the initial average. I decided to store the average in a temporal relation  named avg_salary.

```sql
   with avg_salary(value) as (select avg (salary)
                                 from instructor)
    update instructor
    set salary = salary * 1.05
    where salary < avg_salary.value;
```

When I run the code I am getting an error

> ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'avg.value' in 'where clause'

Comment: @forpas In fact I was just suggesting that. I implemented it  and MySQL threw an error saying that  the relation to be updated can not be referenced in the from clause,

Comment: You are right, MySql does not allow this type of subquery in UPDATE and DELETE statements. I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL update clause does not work like the select or insert clauses where a temporal relation column can be accessed by . operator, e.g this would work fine for the select clause.

```
              with max_budget (value) as
                    (select max(budget)
                    from department)
              select dept_name
              from department, max_budget
              where department.budget = max_budget.value
```

We must run a select sub-query to access the relation's column in the update case.
This solved my problem

```
                            with avg_salary(value) as (select avg (salary)
                                                         from instructor)
                            update instructor
                            set salary = salary * 1.05
                            where salary < (select value
                                            from avg_salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your suggested solution won't work in MySQL.  You cannot reference the table being updated this way.

The simplest solution is a `join`:

```
update instructor i cross join
       (select avg(i2.salary) as avg_salary
        from instructor i2
       ) i2
    set i.salary = i.salary * 1.05
    where i.salary < i2.avg_salary;
```

Comment: It will  . I have run it and it is working.  The with clause will  will store a temporal relation with one record(which  has one field , value).

Comment: No.Your answer seems too complicated for me and inefficient(doing the cross join). If there was a way I could accept both answers I would really appreciate.

Comment: @samuelmayna . . . (1) A `cross join` on one row has almost no overhead.  (2) The accepted answer is no more efficient than this, perhaps very slightly less so because of the unnecessary CTE.